# C# WPF DragDrop event on multiple controls

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, treeview, drag

Hi so i've got a WPF window, 3 different DataGrids and one treeview. My goal is to drag/drop an item from the treeview into a specific datagrid. I've got working code for the drag/drop and its working flawless but my problem is that i don't know how to link the event to other dataviews. So in the 'Drop' event i change the content of my first dataview but i'd like to change the content of the dataview i actually dropped the item on.

this is my code:

For every DataGrid in xaml:

```
Drop="Droptree_Drop" DragEnter="Droptree_DragEnter" AllowDrop="True"
```

My Treeview PreviewMouseMove event:

```
  private void TvDates_PreviewMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                Point mousePos = e.GetPosition(null);
                Vector diff = startPoint - mousePos;

                if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed &&
                   (Math.Abs(diff.X) > SystemParameters.MinimumHorizontalDragDistance ||
                    Math.Abs(diff.Y) > SystemParameters.MinimumVerticalDragDistance))
                {
                    //
                    TreeView tree = sender as TreeView;
                    TreeViewItem tvitem = FindAnchestor<TreeViewItem>((DependencyObject)e.OriginalSource);
                    // Initialize the drag & drop operation
                    DataObject dragData = new DataObject("myFormat", tvDates.SelectedItem.ToString());
                    DragDrop.DoDragDrop(tvitem, dragData, DragDropEffects.Move);

                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

            }

        }
```

Droptree_DragEnter event:

```
 private void Droptree_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!e.Data.GetDataPresent("myFormat") ||
                sender == e.Source)
            {
                e.Effects = DragDropEffects.None;
            }
        }
```

and finally my Drop event:

```
 private void Droptree_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Data.GetDataPresent("myFormat"))
            {
              //  MessageBox.Show(e.Data.GetData("myFormat") as string); Get Item content
                List<string> currentitems = new List<string>();

                foreach (dynamic item in dgChauffeur1.Items)
                {
                    currentitems.Add(item.Orders.ToString());


                }
                currentitems.Add(e.Data.GetData("myFormat") as string);



                dgChauffeur1.ItemsSource = currentitems.Select(s => new { Orders = s }).ToList();  //This is where i have my DataGrid however i want to have the datagrid i dropped my item on.




            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding this code into the event fixed it:

```
DataGrid dg = sender as DataGrid;
dg.ItemsSource = ....
```